# How to import a text file without columns and with hard breaks into vba?

Tags: vba, excel, import

I have built a simple webscraper in VBA that extracts a table from Google Patents and stores the innerHTML in a .txt file (named something like 1234567.txt) for about 23,000 patents. Now I want to analyze the content of each file. To do so, I hope to import the txt files into VBA so that I can do some string searches but that seems to be ludicrously difficult. 
I read about 20 solutions to import .txt files into VBA but none work for my files that look like this:

```
US6824791 B2 ' There is a shift + Enter here
<TD class="patent-data-table-td citation-patent"><A href="/patents/US7767249">US7767249</A></TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td patent-date-value">Jul 25, 2005</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td patent-date-value">Aug 3, 2010</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td ">Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td ">Preparation of nanoparticles</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td citation-patent"><A href="/patents/US7935853">US7935853</A><SPAN class=patent-tooltip-anchor aria-label="Cited by examiner" data-tooltip-text="Cited by examiner" data-tooltip="Cited by examiner" a="null"> *</SPAN></TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td patent-date-value">Oct 8, 2009</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td patent-date-value">May 3, 2011</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td ">Bobelium S.L.</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td ">Micronized composition of a 2,4-disubstituted phenol derivative</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td citation-patent"><A href="/patents/US8524829">US8524829</A></TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td patent-date-value">Jun 17, 2008</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td patent-date-value">Sep 3, 2013</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td ">Brown University Research Foundation</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td ">Methods for micronization of hydrophobic drugs</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td citation-patent"><A href="/patents/EP2422804A1?cl=en">EP2422804A1</A></TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td patent-date-value">Jun 16, 2005</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td patent-date-value">Feb 29, 2012</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td ">Amano Enzyme USA., Ltd.</TD>
<TD class="patent-data-table-td ">Controlled release formulations of enzymes, microorganisms, and antibodies with mucoadhesive polymers</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
' There is a shift + Enter here
```

So despite the fact that the files are neatly structured and repetitive, it seems to be very difficult to import them as a single string. I basically want to loop through the file, and extract the patent number and the 2 dates mentioned (using `Mid` and `InStr`) and put them in three different columns. That's what I think is best but I'm keen to hear smarter suggestions!

It might be relevant to know that every .txt file has a different length (number of rows), but I can estimate the exact number of rows with 99.9% certainty `(1 (title) + 6  * total number of citations (which I know) - 1 (last <TR> is missing)`

Thanks in advance

Simon

EDIT: some examples of things I tried. This codes were taken from online sources. I am not really sure how they should work and it is very possible that I have applied them incorrectly.

```
`Sub Text2Excel_Click()
Dim sourcestring as String

sourcestring = GetText("C\users\...\test.txt")
sourcestring = OpenTextFileToString("C\users\...\test.txt")

Function GetText(sFile As String) As String
   Dim sText As String
   Dim nSourceFile As Integer

   ''Close any open text files
   Close
   ''Get the number of the next free text file
   nSourceFile = FreeFile
   ''Write the entire file to sText
   Open sFile For Input As #nSourceFile
   sText = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
   Close

   GetText = sText
End Function

Function OpenTextFileToString(ByVal strFile As String) As String
' RB Smissaert - Author
Dim hFile As Long
hFile = FreeFile
Open strFile For Input As #hFile
OpenTextFileToString = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
Close #hFile
End Function
```

I also tried the following [suggestion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a77w6kkx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): but that gives me the runtime error 424 "object required".

Comment: I can just take the text (after adding the `<TABLE>` and `<TBODY>` opening tags at the start - probably only missing because you have only posted a small part of the data), save it as a .html file, and use File/Open in Excel to import it into a standard spreadsheet.  Does this not work for you?

Comment: I showed all the data I have. The <TABLE> and <TBODY> have been deleted in the gathering of the file. Did not know I was going to need them, so I do not have them. Saving as html and opening in excel might be possible but I don't know how to do this for > 20.000 text files. Doing it manually for each file does not seem like a sensible option...

Comment: So you have a lot of fragments of HTML tables you want to pull data from.  I'm still not completely sure what you're having trouble with: which bit of the process isn't working (actually opening the files, looping through rows, finding the data)?  Which VBA functions have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: I just need one function that allows me to read in the file into vba. I thought it was extremely simple but I don't seem to find any workable solution. So I have the example I gave stored under C:\Users\simon\Desktop\test.txt and I want to read that file into VBA and call it sourcestring. So I tried something like `Dim sourcestring As String sourcestring = "C:\Users\simon\Desktop\test.txt" and 100 variants (with EOF and LOF)` but nothing works. Sometimes I get the first line only (probably due to the hardbreak. Generally I get an error

Comment: 23,000 files?  How many citations per file?  
I would think you would read the files with Open, Line Input,  
and Close so you could extract the fields you want.  
Your code doesn't seem to do any extraction of data.

Comment: @dromley Indeed at the moment the code does not extract data. Little point in writing code to extract specific substrings and store them in an excel file (which is the goal) if I cannot read in the file. Line Input, I have tried it but I can't make it work. Could you share a short example of how `Line Input` could help me store the text file in a string I can work with please? Fyi on average 6 citations per file, which means for all 23,000 about 36 * 23,000 rows if I would join all text files in one big file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to get the text file into 1 string in vba then you can use the following function.

NOTE: This requires you to add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**.

```
Public Function ReadFileAsString(ByVal filePath As String) As String

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set txtstream = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading, False)

Dim sourceString As String
Do While Not txtstream.AtEndOfStream
    sourceString = sourceString + txtstream.ReadLine
Loop

ReadFileAsString = sourceString
txtstream.Close

Set fso = Nothing
Set txtstream = Nothing

End Function
```

Then you can do InStr() and Mid() etc on the string the above function returns. To see the text file try:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print ReadFileAsString("C:\Users\ausername\Desktop\test.txt")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi again. I tried your solution but it does not work apparently. I only get the first line of the document (the hard break might be causing this) and there is a space between every single letter... Any way to get the rest read as well?

Comment: Assuming you mean Shift+Enter for hard breaks, this works for me. How are you using it?

Comment: I do mean shift + enter and it's strange. It does not work for me. It actually only gives as a result (I added `MsgBox sourceString`) something that looks like ypU but the y has an umlaut, the p is actually a p and a b on top of each other and U is a normal capital U. None of these symbols appear in the text. Btw, I tested a text without the Shift + Enter combination and that one worked perfectly. PS there is also a Shift + Enter combo in the very end of text, and the visualisation of the Shift + Enter is the symbol for male - circle and upward pointing arrow

Comment: Im not sure how knowing this information might help, but what version of excel are you on? What's your OS and default language?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply again. I'm actually thinking it's working. I'm not kidding but your code only does not seem to work for the file I called test.txt (no idea why). I tried a few others which have the hard enter and they did work perfectly and superfast. But FYI, I'm, on Excel 2010, Windows 7, default English UK. But as said, I think it works. Let me run a few more trials and if it holds, I will more than gladly accept your answer. You've been a life saver!